# Which stats test to use? Multiple Independent variables?

Tags: statistical-significance, anova, multivariate-analysis, spss

I'm working on a research project without much of a stats background so I need some help with figuring out which stats test to use currently.

I think I have multiple dependent variables to look at, and two levels of independent variables. As an example, I'd like to look at how both skin pigmentation (light, medium, dark) and hair color (light, medium dark) affect skin cancer outcomes so those are my independent variables, and then the dependent variables would be like, frequency of treatments, change in tumor size, etc.

I did Kruskal Wallis and Pearson Chi square to get P values using SPSS for the independent variables separately, like outcomes just based on skin pigmentation, and then outcomes based on the different hair colors.
But I would like to look at the outcomes of the different hair colors applied under each skin pigmentation level - ex. mean survival time of people in each hair color who ALSO have light skin.
So I guess I have 9 groups to look at total- 3 skin pigmentation types, then 3 hair colors within each type (3x3). Is this factorial? Would I use factorial ANOVA or some sort of multivariable analysis?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have any other variables that are associated with skin cancer risk, aside from skin pigmentation and hair color? If not, then it would be hard to do meaningful analysis. Also, are (light, medium, dark) pigmentation and (light, medium dark) hair color standard categorizations in your field of study? They seem more like stereotypes, to me at least.

Comment: ^need to clarify that those variables are just used as an example, i was looking more for advice on the type of stats test to use

Comment: I suggest the following approach: Pick the most important (clinically relevant?) outcome and try to develop a valid & meaningful model for it. This would depend in no small part on the availability (and careful description) of relevant covariates. Once you have a good model for one outcome, then think about the rest.

Comment: On further thought, it might be too early for a model. First, take a long, cricital look at your data and the covariates. Do you have information on what's relevant for skin cancer risk according to previous research? Do the covariates measure what they are supposed to measure? For example, skin pigmentation and hair color seem attributes that change in time for most people.